# Rewriting a URL with a variable number of query string parameters using slashes instead in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-rewriting, routes

Not sure if this is even possible, but I am working in ASP.NET 4.5+ and would like to achieve the following.

I have a sample URL that I am testing with locally that reads:

http://localhost:5000/search/?page=1&count=15&sort=0&fType=tags&fValue=Tablecloths+%26+Tablecloth+Sets&Categories=EVENTS&landingPageType=1

Instead of ampersands and equal signs to delimit query string parameters/key-value pairs, I would like the URL to be restructured as follows:

http://localhost:5000/search/?page/1/count/15/sort/0/fType/tags/fValue/Tablecloths+%26+Tablecloth+Sets/Categories/EVENTS/landingPageType/1

Essentially, what will happen when this URL is hit is that it will be rewritten behind the scenes to match the former URL. The goal is to boost ranking by structuring my URLs to be more SEO-friendly.

The sample URL mentioned above will only apply to the /search route BUT may have a variable number of URL query parameters. When the url string is split on the '/', the odd tokens will always be a key and the even tokens will always be a value. (eg. /search/?{key}/{value}/{key}/{value})

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite?

Comment: Yes, but I can't seem to find a solution that achieves anything remotely close to what I need